# How to find variables s.t a matrix becomes diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

How can I find the values a, b, c, d, e, f so that the following matrix becomes diagonalizable?

A =
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a & b & c\\
0 & 0 & d & e\\
0 & 0 & 1 & f\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{array} \right) $

I know I need to have a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ formed by eigenvectors of A.
I find the characteristic polynomial using the determinant.
Thus my $\lambda^2(\lambda - 1)(\lambda -2) $.

Therefore $\lambda \in \{0, 1, 2\}$. I found the respective matrix for each one, and I understand I need to get a dimension of 2 for 0 because its multiplicity is 2, while it has to be 1 for $\lambda$ 1 and 2.

$A - I0$ =
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a & b & c\\
0 & 0 & d & e\\
0 & 0 & 1 & f\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{array} \right) $

$A - I1$ =
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & a & b & c\\
0 & -1 & d & e\\
0 & 0 & 0 & f\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} \right) $

$A - I2$ =
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-2 & a & b & c\\
0 & -2 & d & e\\
0 & 0 & -1 & f\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right) $

I can't figure it out, can someone hint me?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533130/find-all-a-b-c-d-e-f-for-which-the-matrix-mathcala-is-digonalizable

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix $A-0I$ can be row-reduced to
$$\pmatrix{0&a&b&c\cr0&0&1&f\cr0&0&0&2\cr0&0&0&0\cr}\ .$$
Now $A$ is diagonalisable if and only if this matrix has $2$ non-leading columns, and that occurs for one specific value of $a$.  The values of $b,c,d,e,f$ are irrelevant.

See if you can finish the problem from here.